# Is there a NetLogo precedence table?

Tags: netlogo

Is there a specification of the precedence values of NetLogo terms? Or if NetLogo parsing not precedence oriented, is there a description of its grammar? In other words, when writing NetLogo code, is there a good reference for syntax correctness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the docs:](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#syntax)

> Operator precedences are as follows, high to low:
>
> - with, at-points, in-radius, in-cone
> - (all other primitives and user-defined procedures)
> - ^
> - *, /, mod
> - +, -
> - <, >, <=, >=
> - =, !=
> - and, or, xor

Comment: Thank you very much. I had done a search and didn't find anything. Now I've found it. Must have searched badly the last time.